# how i can access an action method without defining the Controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a web application, and i have Home controller with three action methods; Index,About, contact.
now to access the About action method i need to type the following url `https://servername/home/about` so my question is if i can access the About action method without referencing the "Home" controller class. such as `"http://servername/About/"` thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a specific route in your `RouteConfig.cs` file

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "About",
  url: "About",
  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "About" }
);
```

and ensure this is before the default route